# How to redirect the user back to the custom action after login/logout in IdentityServer IDP?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I want the IdentityServer4 as an IDP, returns back to my custom action, after Login and Logout..how could I achieve this?

e.g: 
http://myclient.com/account/ExternalLoginCallBack
,
http://myclient.com/account/ExternalLogoutCallBack

should I use the oidc Events?

I know the **signin-oidc** and **signout-callback-oidc** are the default return_url in oidc flow and handled by the oidc flow on behalf, but I want to do some local actions after the user signed in and signed out to the idp.

I changed the default **CallbackPath** of oidc in startup (in client):

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", config =>
 {
  config.CallbackPath = "/account/ExternalLoginCallBack";
```

but it doesn't work in action; I can see my **return_uri** (mentioned above) in the browser address bar, and the idp POSTing to that, but I can't handle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CallbackPath` is the path where server will redirect after authentication. It's automatically handled by the OIDC middleware itself, We don’t need to create/handle this in our application, the middleware will handle this.

If you want to redirect to specific action after login , you can manually set `RedirectUri` of `AuthenticationProperties` :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("signin")]
public async Task SignIn()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc", new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "/YourController/YourAction",
        });
    }
}
```

Redirect to specific action after logout :

```
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/YourController/YourAction" }, "Cookies", "oidc");
}
```